# How do I use indexOf with an If Statement in Java?

Tags: java

I am working on a program that when you enter an email incorrectly, it will show you an error message. If it's empty, the message will tell you it can't be blank. If there's more than 30 characters, it has to be less or equal to 30 and so on. The program I am having is that I've never used indexOf inside of an If statement. How do I code if it the input Email Address can only have one AtSign(@)? or Code that if there isn't a @ sign or there's more than 2, an error message will show up.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class EmailandGrade {

public static void main(String[] args) {

        // 1. Declaring Variables

        String strEmail;



        // 2. Print Prompts and User Input
        strEmail = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a user email:");

        // 3. If/Else Statements For Email
        if (strEmail.isEmpty())
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Can't be blank");
        }
        else if (strEmail.length() > 30)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Email must be less than or equal 30 characters");
        }
        else if (!strEmail.endsWith("@student.stcc.edu"))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Must end with in: @student.stcc.edu");
        }
        else if (strEmail.indexOf("@") )
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Can only have one @ in it");
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

If [`String.indexOf(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-) doesn't find the requested sub string it returns `-1` as noted in the linked Javadoc. So you can test for that like,

```
else if (strEmail.indexOf("@") == -1)
```

Then you need to write another test to check for two (or more) `@` signs. Perhaps using [`String.lastIndexOf(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf-java.lang.String-) like,

```
else if (strEmail.indexOf("@") == -1 || 
        strEmail.indexOf("@") != strEmail.lastIndexOf("@"))
```

Comment: @Drizzy If your question is answered, please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/243725) the answer you found most helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check valid email. there is two way to check it.
1. Manually check for string is not empty valid length, pattern and other stuff.
2. You can use java's Pattern and Matcher.That's only suggestion

Ans 1.

`String.indexOf(character)` method returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified character or -1, if the character does not occur. So you need to add

```
else if (strEmail.indexOf("@") == -1)
```

Ans 2.
You just need to set regex to validate email address.

```
public class EmailValidator {

    private Pattern pattern;
    private Matcher matcher;

    private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN =
        "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
        + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

    public EmailValidator() {
        pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
    }

    public boolean validate(final String hex) {

        matcher = pattern.matcher(hex);
        return matcher.matches();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
else if (strEmail.indexOf("@") != -1)
```

An example of how to use indexOf is just right above. Basically, indexOf returns the index of the string if it is found. Then it returns -1 if it is not found.